# How to change height of the map element on button click?

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I want to remove the styling  back and forth on button click  but when i try to resize now the map is  rendering all over the screen but without any background, only the markers that were on it.

So basically i want to remove the styling and hide the list element and only display the map element on one click and on the next one to display again the list and to resize the map  how it was initially.

any ideas ?

```
**Updated**

  **aura component** 

<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="map" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="buttonstate" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<div aura:id= "screen">        
 <div id="map" aura:id="mapSize" class="mapSize" style="position:relative;">   
        <lightning:button class="button" aura:id="buttonList" label="Button" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" />
 </div>
</div>
   <div  aura:id="listDiv" class ="listDiv">
   <c:List  />
    </div>        
  </div>       
</aura:component>

**CSS**

   .cAccountMap .mapSize{
   width: 100%;
   height: 80%; 
}

.cAccountMap .mapTestSize{
    height: 100%;
}


.THIS .listDiv{
 height: 20%;
}

}

**Javascript** 

   handleClick : function(component,event,helper){
      var buttonName = event.getSource();
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("listDiv");
     var buttonstate = component.get('v.buttonstate');
    var cmpTarget = component.find('mapSize');
    if(buttonstate==false){
        buttonName.set('v.label', 'LALA');
        elements[0].style.display = 'none';
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'mapSize');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'mapTestSize');      
    }else{
        buttonName.set('v.label', 'gogo');
        elements[0].style.display = '';
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'mapSize');

        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'mapTestSize');  
    }
    component.set('v.buttonstate', !buttonstate);

}
```

Comment: I saw `.This` and `.THIS` in your CSS. What is this ?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you , i updated.

Comment: can you share your complete code including `.buttonstate` button? Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui i added the code that i managed to make it work but now the map is all over the screen without background, basically is showing only the  markers that were on the map without background. Also  i checked and for some reason on salesforce mobile app is not displaying the map anymore only grey.  Thanks

Comment: have you deployed your code on any server or any working example? Please share the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After multiple tries  i managed to find the solution 
aura component is the same

css 
.cAccountMap .mapSize{
  width: 100%;
  height: 65%; 
}

.THIS .listDiv{
 height: 35%;
}

.THIS .listHideDiv{
 height: 0%;
}
```

Javascript

```
 handleClick : function(component,event,helper){
    var changeViewButton = event.getSource();
    var listDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("listDiv");
    var mapDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mapSize");
    var buttonstate = component.get('v.buttonstate');
    var cmpList = component.find('listDiv');

    if(buttonstate==false){
        changeViewButton.set('v.label', 'lala');
        listDiv[0].style.display = 'none';
        mapDiv[0].style.height = '100%';
        $A.util.addClass(cmpList, 'listHideDiv');
    }else{
        changeViewButton.set('v.label', 'gogo');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpList, 'listHideDiv');
        listDiv[0].style.display = '';
        mapDiv[0].style.height = '65%';
    }
    component.set('v.buttonstate', !buttonstate);

}
```

So basically the map height style was changed from javascript